# My python programm keep printing the same id event if i want it to print the others too

Tags: python

I'm new in your community but i have a problem on one of my code.I am developping a program which is use to summerize the shell command 'show vlan' and 'show mac address-table' to a table with only the informations we want it to print. Those informations are the vlan Ids of the switch we are using, the number of vlan per mac adresses and the number of mac adresses which are dynamic. Unfortunately, it keep on printing only one vlan id and not the others of the switch, and it's always the same one.i'd like to resolve the problem. I'm a junior on python and i'm pretty sure my code is wrong somewhere but i don't know where.

i used this example of the devnet website to find a way to code what i was asked to code:

[an example of the command 'show interface brief' in a code from devnet website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tgkG.png)

This is my code:

```
import json
import cisco
from cli import *

shVlan = json.loads(clid('show vlan'))

shMacAdr = json.loads(clid('show mac address-table'))

mac_counter = 0

print('  | VlanId | @Mac/vlan')
print('--|--------|-----------')

for i in range (0, len(shVlan['TABLE_vlanbrief']['ROW_vlanbrief'])):

    vlan = shVlan['TABLE_vlanbrief']['ROW_vlanbrief'][i]

    vlanId = int(vlan['vlanshowbr-vlanid'])

for j in range (0, len(shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address'] ['ROW_mac_address'])):

    mac_adr = shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address']['ROW_mac_address'][j]

    if mac_adr['disp_vlan'] == vlan['vlanshowbr-vlanid']:

         mac_counter = mac_counter + 1

total_mac_dyn = 0

for k in range (0, len (shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address']['ROW_mac_address'])):

     mac = shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address']['ROW_mac_address'][k]

         if mac['disp_is_static'] == 'disabled':

             total_mac_dyn = total_mac_dyn + 1

l = 0

while l < len(shVlan['TABLE_vlanbrief']['ROW_vlanbrief']) and l <   len(shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address']['ROW_mac_address']):
     l = l +1
     print('%2d| %5d  | %5d') % (l, vlanId, mac_counter)
     print('--|--------|-----------')

print('Total @Mac dynamiques| %2d') % (total_mac_dyn)
print('---------------------|----')
```

i used the sandbox of cisco to find the table of my switch: 
i asked: 
[the command show vlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8cuV.png)

and i converted it so i can see what's inside the switch, that is what i took for my table shVlan (in my code):

[the answer from the cisco sandbox for a show vlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCi69.png)

then i did the same with the 'show mac-address table' command:

[show mac address-table ask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3IL6.png)

and i converted it so i could see what was inside the switch so that i could use it for my table shMacAdr(in my code):
that's the answer of the convertion:

[answer of the sandbox for 'show mac address-tabe' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbvp.png)

and that's the out put of my code with the command 'pyhton bootflash:/scripts(because it's in scripts doc)/ mac_vlan.py(because it's the name of my file)':

[out put of my code which keep printing only one id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL7u6.png)

I hope i made it clearer i still don't understand well how to make myself understandable sorry for the screens that's the only thing i found to illustrates how i thoght for creating my code.

Comment: Hello @YoruTakara and welcome. I'd like to suggest you to take your time to improve your question's formatting: you'll have more chance to get a satisfying answer! In particular, check why [you shouldn't post image of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [ask]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. And when you post a screenshot, use the computer's screenshot feature, don't take a picture with a cellphone.

Comment: The loops that look up all the VLAN information need to put their results in a list. You're just overwriting the `vlanId` variable each time, so at the end it just has the last value.

Comment: You don't need both the `for j` and `for k` loops. You can add up both totals in the same loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but how do i do that? ^^ sorry but i'm juste in my first year of programming...

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can learn to improve your code.

1) Looping through array:
When you are looping through an array you can use

```py
for array_element in array:
    another_array.append(array_element)
```

2) When you wanted to loop through 2 or more arrays at the same time, you can use zip

```py
for element1, element2 in zip(array1, array2):
    # do something with element1 and element2
```

using zip you'll achieve the same functionality as you obtain using

```
while i < len(array1) and i < len(array2):
    element1 = array1[i]
    element2 = array2[i]
    i = i + 1
```

So replace the for i loop and for j loop and last while loop with the following code

```py
mac_counter = 0
for vlan, mac_addr in zip(shVlan['TABLE_vlanbrief'][['ROW_vlanbrief'], shMacAdr['TABLE_mac_address']['ROW_mac_address']):
    vlanId = int(vlan["vlanshowbr-vlanid"])
    # same with mac_addr
    # test fields of mac_addr and update mac_counter
    # print them
```

Comment: Oh thanks i didn't know that!! i'll change it right now!

Comment: thanks for making it clearer i'll try what you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

My question have been solved thank you all for your help and your kindness towards me!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

vlanId going to be overwritten at every iteration your loop does. 
Therefor you always get only the last Id back that have been found.

you better use a list and append the different Ids

Comment: If you're not going to show how to do it, this should just be a comment, not an answer. And I already posted this comment.

Comment: one way to realise it could be as follows:
vlanId = []

for i in vlan_list:
    vlanId[i] = int(vlan['vlanshowbr-vlanid'])

in your while loop, where you print out your vlans you could do 

while l < your_list:
    print('%2d| %5d  | %5d') % (l, vlanId[l], mac_counter)

that should bring your vlanId together with your counter